# Jboss startup ownership issue

Tags: permissions, rhel, jboss

Facing few issues with `jboss` startup . After `jboss` startup , permission of few files got changed because of which we had to manually change the files and start `jboss` .

```
 $ ls -l /etc/init.d/online
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 600 admin 11 Jun 18  2012 /etc/init.d/online -> jboss

 $ ls -l /etc/init.d/jboss
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 600 admin 5266 Mar 12  2014 /etc/init.d/jboss
```

Files that are getting changed are `log location and few directories like  data/ tmp/ work/`  under that particular jboss instance directory. The files are getting owned by `root:root` , but we have to manually change it to `jboss:admin`  user and start jboss for it to work properly . Jboss is running as 'jboss' user in the system. The issue occurs only during system reboot when the application starts but during manual start of jboss , we are not seeing the issue.

Startup of app during system reboot looks as follows

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc3.d/S85online
 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 Aug 14  2012 /etc/rc3.d/online -> ../init.d/jboss

$ chkconfig  online --list
jboss 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Start/Stop component contents of  /etc/init.d/jboss script are as follows:

```
start() {
 ulimit -n 32768
 ulimit -s 20240
 ulimit -u 4096

 su -m jboss -c "${BIN}/${APP}.sh start" && success || failure
}

stop() {
# echo  "Stopping ${PROGNAME} .."
 su -m jboss -c "${BIN}/${APP}.sh stop" && success || failure
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
      ${BIN}/${APP}.sh stop && success || failure
  fi
 }
```

What changes needs to be done so that the owner does not get changed to `root`. Will it get resolve if we change the owner of init scripts under `/etc/init.d/` to root` ?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `jboss` init script - it sounds like the script itself isn't starting the daemon as the `jboss` user. I'm guessing that when you start it manually you `su` to `jboss` first?

Comment: Added the contents of jboss init script. Manually we are doing su - root to start jboss